# Why can I not see my ATG logging in my JBOSS console?

Tags: java, logging, jboss, atg

As I understand it, ATG has its own logging mechanism. One of the LogListeners in ATG is a ScreenLogListener which then uses Java logging to log any incoming log messages. These show up in the JBOSS console.

In my current environment - a development environment I set up myself using CIM - I cannot see any ATG logging in the JBOSS console.

I can see log messages coming from log4j in one of my web applications in the same EAR, but nothing from ATG

All the relevant ATG settings seem to be correct (for example in GLOBAL.properties) as well as for the specific component. I can see ATG logs in the relevant server logs (e.g. debug.log, error.log) under ${ATG_HOME}/servers/{server-name}/logs.

ScreenLog.useInfoForDebug is true.

I am guessing that there is something not right with my JBOSS application Java logging configuration. Where can I see this to be able to diagnose it?

I am using ATG 10.0.3 and JBoss 5.1.0 on CentOS

Comment: Which version of ATG and JBoss are you working on? Things changed quite a bit for JBoss 6.1 EAP and ATG 11.0.

Comment: ATG 10.0.3 and JBoss 5.1.0 on CentOS 6.5

Answer (score 0):

Check the log4j config file `<jboss-home>/server/configdir/conf/jboss-log4j.xml`.  You might need to add:

```
<category name="org.jboss">
   <priority value="DEBUG" />
   <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</category>
```